# Xcode hung on 'waiting for other symbol processing'

Tags: ios, xcode, organizer

It appears that since I updated my iPad to iOS 5.01 I can't debug it via xCode.

When I attach the iPad both Xcode and the organiser display "waiting for other symbol processing" which shows indefinitely.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you updated XCode to the latest version?

Comment: Actual alert text is: "waiting on other symbol processing" Copied here for the benefit of search engine crawlers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if it fixes the problem every time, but this has worked for me in the past:

1. Quit out of Xcode,
2. Delete the `.copying_lock` file in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 <DOUBLE CHECK THE NUMBER HERE, IT COULD BE 5.0 or 5.0.1 (abc), etc>/`.

   This can be done in Terminal.app with the command:

   ```
   sudo rm /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1/.copying_lock
   ```
3. Run Xcode again.  Now the symbol import should start right up and the "Waiting" message should be gone.

---

If that doesnt work, try deleting the numbered folder itself, then restart xcode again.  If that also doesnt work, reinstall xcode maybe?

Comment: Thanks, in the end i re-installed x-code which did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 6.1 you just have to delete contents of these two folders:

1. /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Logs
2. /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport

Quit and restart the xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the problem for me

1. Quit XCode
2. Open Terminal and run the following commands

   ```
   chmod 64 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0(the correct number)/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg
   chmod 64 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0(the correct number)/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature
   ```
3. Restart XCode

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself, and it was because I had an NSLog call in an event that was triggered way more times than I expected. It caused a bottleneck of data from my iPad to my Mac.

I solved it by disconnecting my iPad. I then terminated the app on the iPad using iPad functionality and let Xcode do its thing. It cleared itself up in about half a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Xcode 5 and I just restarted and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I inadvertently unplugged my phone while the app was running though Xcode and then when I tried again, this message kept coming up, even if I tried other devices. I tried restarting Xcode and then restarted my Mac but it still brought the same message up. The solution for me was simply to remove the app from the device and re-run it.